# imageTtftext не находит шрифт

Tags: php, шрифты, gd

Когда я прописываю путь к шрифт в функции `imagetfftext();`
Появляется злосчастная ошибка

```
imagettftext(); could not find/open font
```

код (php 7.2):

```php
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$font = "./arial.tff";
imagettftext(imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30), 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, "text");
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: Добавьте строку кода с этим вызовом, со всеми аргументами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imagettftext.php):

> Во многих случаях, когда шрифт находится в том же каталоге, что и
> скрипт PHP, поможет следующий трюк.
>
> ```
> <?php
> // Установка переменной окружения для GD
> putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
>
> // Имя шрифта для использования (обратите внимание, что расширение .ttf не указывается)
> $font = 'SomeFont';
> ```

Можно попробовать передать абсолютный путь к шрифту:

```
$font = realpath('./arial.ttf');
```

Или

```
$font = __DIR__.'/arial.ttf';
```

Comment: этот трюк у меня не работает (

Comment: Вы положили шрифт `arial.ttf` в папку со скриптом, и присвоили `$font = 'arial';`?

Comment: Да, я положил там где файл со скриптом

Comment: опять не работает (